# What are these corresponding instructions in NASM?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, nasm

I find these instructions in pseudo code generated by IDA Pro
and I am trying to translate them into NASM syntax code

```
fadd    st, st(1)
fxch    st(1)
fucomi  st, st(1)
```

I searched in the nasm manual, and see examples like this:

```
    fadd    st1             ; this sets st0 := st0 + st1
    fadd    st0, st1        ; so does this

    fadd    st1, st0        ; this sets st1 := st1 + st0
    fadd    to st1          ; so does this
```

What I am confused is how to translate **st**? 
is it equal to st0?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Some information here about Masm/Nasm differences:
http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.6

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you and what I am confused is how to translate "st"? st(0) can be st0, and st(1) can be st1...